# Powershell - disable all cmdlets such as Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, security

I'm looking for a method to completely disable (once and for all) all cmdlets in the powershell (v.5) which are trying to interact with web sites or any other servers exposed to the Internet (cmdlet like Invoke-WebRequest). I don't want to disable the powershell execution completely on my windows machines - just trying to harden the powershell execution policy. I already used Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted for all scripts however these web methods are still being executed.

Comment: take a look at constrained endpoints and JEA.